# What are those persian texts on CS series?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike, counter-strike-source

I have been playing Counter Strike series since I was a child.
I was used to play the cracked version of CS 1.6 and the CS Source which I had downloaded from Iranian websites.
So I thought the Iranian version had added those text to the maps but now I have bought the original CS GO from Steam then I saw some Persian texts on map again.  What are they supposed to mean?

There many Arabic texts on DUST2 because it refers to Plastine but it was very strange to me that a Persian text was there too. Why would be there a Persian sentence on terrorist base?

The sentence in CS GO is

> *فریمن اینجا بود

Which means "*freeman was here"*

And the sentence in CS source is

> سی اس سورس باحاله

Which mean "CS Source is interesting"

Comment: the first is a reference to the main protagonist of Half Life

Comment: It's a mix of Persian words and some other meaningless words, not Arabic.

Comment: @Err Hunter but there are many arabic sentence in the game it is not strange for arabic to be in the game but why persian ?

Answer (score 4):

They phrases are easter eggs.

`Freeman was here` is a reference to Gordon Freeman, the main character from Half Life. Half Life is not only made by the same developers, but Counter-Strike was originally made as a modification of Half Life 1.

`Cs source is interesting` just means that Counter-Strike Source is cool.

Comment: Are you sure they don't just mean "Counter-Strike: Source" (CSS) instead of the Counter-Strike Source Code?

Comment: @private_meta, the OP had actually written "CS:S". I am not sure why the editor added in "code". I suspect they are unfamiliar with the game, and assumed source to mean "source code"